# Метод onFailure() отлавливает ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

Метод `onFailure()` отлавливает ошибку

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference.

Как это можно исправить?

Код:

```
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {

    private static RequestInterface requestInterface;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Object> items;
    Context context;


    public ShopFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);

        requestInterface = Controller.getApi();

        items = new ArrayList<>();


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_recycle_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        requestInterface.getProduct().enqueue(new Callback <List<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <List<Product>> call, Response <List<Product>> response) {
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                items.addAll(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call <List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, а исключение, разные понятия.

Comment: Наверное, проблема тут: `Toast.makeText(context, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. Попробуйте например, вместо тоаста просто в логи выводить ошибку

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, поздравляю, кстати)

Comment: @DevOma, спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Не вижу, где вы инициализируете `context`?

2) Я считаю лучше использовать вместо этого [getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29), то есть так:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```